# react query mutation isLoading turns false when switching tabs

Tags: reactjs

Usually isLoading() returns true if the mutation is currently executing. But whenever I switch tabs and come back to the original tab, isLoading() is false, even if the mutation is still running. Is there another way to check if the mutation is still running where isLoading() stays true even when I switch tabs?

This is where I return a useMutation:

```
export function exportFunction(
  options: UseMutationOptions<string, unknown, Core.Paths.CreateExportDocument.RequestBody>
) {
  const logError = useLogError();

  return useMutation(
    async exportFilter => {
      const {data} = await axios.post<Core.Paths.CreateExportDocument.RequestBody, AxiosResponse<string>>(
        "/pdncore/api/export/assortmentProducts",
        exportFilter
      );

      const {data: blob} = await axios.get(`/pdncore/api/export/document/excel/${data}`, {responseType: "blob"});
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    },
    {
      ...options,
      onError: (err, vars, context) => {
        logError("error", err);
        options.onError?.(err, vars, context);
      },
    }
  );
}
```

Here is where I execute this function

```
  const myMutation = exportFunction({
    onSuccess: url => {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.download = `export-${new Date().toISOString()}.xlsx`;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    },
  });
```

And this is the button I return

```
<Button
    startIcon={myMutation.isLoading ? <CircularProgress size={20} /> : <GetApp />}
    disabled={myMutation.isLoading}
    onClick={() => myMutation.mutate(exportFilter)}
    >
</Button>
```

Comment: You can use the `isFetching` prop of the [useQuery](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery). As per docs, `isFetching: Is true whenever a request is in-flight, which includes initial loading as well as background refetches.`

Comment: @JunaidFaryad Thank you, that looks promising! Do you happen to know how I can retrieve this property?

Comment: There is a example on the react query [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/simple), on which you can see the useQuery in action. `useQuery` basically returns the `isFetching` prop same as `isLoading` prop.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad I checked and my mutation doesn't have a method isFetching, only isLoading, isSuccess, isError, isIdle, isPaused, status, context, etc. Do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If `isLoading` not working for you, you can create a new react state (maybe `loading` or `inProgress`)  and use the `onSuccess` and `onError` options parameters to update the `loading` state yourself in the [useMutation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation). You initially set the `state loading` parameter to true and then in the `onSuccess` and `onError` callbacks, you can make the state variable `false`.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad Okay thank you for the suggestion. I added the function where I return a useMutation. Where in the function can I create the react state?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I think a better approach is to send the `onError` and `onSuccess`  in the options parameter, from the code, where you're calling the `exportFunction`. If you can share the code from the file, where you're executing this function, I can take a better look.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad Okay I added the code.

Comment: I've added some code in the answer, although, it's little weird why the `isLoading` not working in the mutation. If the below code not works, than maybe a code reproduction `codesandbox` might be needed to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and correct way is to use the useIsMutating hook.

https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useIsMutating#_top

Example:

```
  import { useIsMutating } from 'react-query'

  const isMutation = useIsMutating({
    mutationKey: 'youmutationkey',
    exact: true
  })

  <Button
    startIcon={myMutation.isLoading || isMutation > 0 ? <CircularProgress size={20} /> : <GetApp />}
    disabled={myMutation.isLoading || isMutation > 0}
    onClick={() => myMutation.mutate(exportFilter)}
    >
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use a local state, if the returned value for `isLoading` in the mutation is not working for you. Initialize state

```
const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false) //user any name for the flag
```

Then in your button, when you actually mutate the call, you can update the code to as below, which is checking for the state variable, we declared above to store the progress of the mutation and also update the state variable in mutate call.

```
<Button
    startIcon={myMutation.isLoading || isPending ? <CircularProgress size={20} /> : <GetApp />}
    disabled={myMutation.isLoading || isPending} // state variable
    onClick={() => {
      setIsPending(true)
      myMutation.mutate(exportFilter)
    }>
</Button>
```

Then please also update the mutation callbacks

```
  const myMutation = exportFunction({
  onSuccess: url => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.download = `export-${new Date().toISOString()}.xlsx`;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    setIsPending(false)
  },
  onError: (err, vars, context) => {
    logError("error", err); // in case you want to log in the component
    options.onError?.(err, vars, context);
    setIsPending(false)
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I adjusted my code and unfortunately it's still the same problem as before. When I switch tabs and come back to the original tab, the button is enabled again, even if the mutation is still loading.

Comment: Could you please create a reproducible example in the codesandbox or some other plaftorm to debug this issue. Regarding the button is enabled on switching tabs is due to the fact, that this code `myMutation.mutate(exportFilter)` is triggering the mutation and `isLoading`, and this code is programmed to execute on button click. Once someone clicks on the button, then the mutation starts running. If you want to run the mutation every time component renders (on page load or switch tabs etc), than you need to run this code `myMutation.mutate(exportFilter)` in `useEffect` instead of `button Click`